Nextjs Error: async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components
This error keeps showing to me as I import the AppTransactionsButton on my Transaction Page:
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components. This error is often caused by accidentally adding 'use client' to a module that was originally written for the server.
Here is the following code transactions/page.tsx:
import { DataTable } from "@/app/_components/ui/data-table";
import { db } from "@/app/_lib/prisma";
import { transactionsColumns } from "./_columns";
import AddTransaction from "../_components/add-transaction-button";

const TransactionsPage = async () => {
  const transactions = await db.transaction.findMany({});

  return (
    <div className="space-y-6 p-6">
      <div className="flex w-full justify-between items-center">
        <h2 className="text-2xl font-bold">Transactions</h2>
        <AddTransaction />
      </div>
      <DataTable columns={transactionsColumns} data={transactions} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default TransactionsPage;

And here is the components/add-transactions-buttons.tsx:
"use client";

import { Button } from "./ui/button";
import {
  Dialog,
  DialogContent,
  DialogDescription,
  DialogHeader,
  DialogTitle,
  DialogTrigger,
} from "./ui/dialog";
import { ArrowDownUpIcon } from "lucide-react";

const AddTransactionButton = () => {
  return (
    <Dialog>
      <DialogTrigger>
        <Button>
          <ArrowDownUpIcon />
          Add Transactions
        </Button>
      </DialogTrigger>
      <DialogContent>
        <DialogHeader>
          <DialogTitle>Add Transaction</DialogTitle>
          <DialogDescription>
            Insert the transaction details below
          </DialogDescription>
        </DialogHeader>
      </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  );
};

export default AddTransactionButton;


Components aren't async functions, they render immediately based on their current props and state. So use useState and useEffect or useCallback in your component function if you need to get data from some asynchronous source, instead.
